# Docker: can't access other container's ports with its name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have two containers with different default networks and I want to communicate with each other. First I made a common network named *"my_network"* then enter into the *container1*'s bash. I could ping the other container by name (*container2*) but when I tried to check the telnet with port 4000, I got the error:

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Curl request also didn't work. But, when I replaced the container name with the host's ip address (eg. 10.244.140.92), everything just worked fine. So what am I doing wrong?

My simplified compose:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
networks:
    my_network:
        driver: bridge
        external: true
    default:    
services:
    container1:
        image: ...
        ports:
            - 5000:80
            - 5001:443
        networks:
            - default
            - my_network



version: "3.9"
networks:
    my_network:
services:
    container2:
        image: ...
        ports:
            - 4000:4000
        networks:
            - my_network
```

Comment: Try `external: true` in container2 network

Comment: Then the docker won't create the my_network and the compose fails